# How to return 0 upon EOF

Tags: c

I have a program that needs to take input until EOF and because this is an assignment, I am constrained to using scanf. I am doing something like this in the main function:

```
while (1){
    
    int x;

    int s=scanf("%d",&x);
    if (x==EOF){
        break;
    }

    if(s==0){
        fprintf(stderr, "Non integer value input.");
        return 1;
    }else if(something){...}
}
return 0;
```

But if I press ^D, the program goes into an infinite loop instead of exiting with 0 and sometimes I just keep seeing ^D on the terminal. How can I fix this?

Another approach I tried looked something like this:

```
char c;

    if (c==EOF){
        break;
    }
    int x=c+0;
```

PS I also tried doing while(x!=EOF) and while (!EOF) for the loop but that doesn't work either.

Comment: EOF is not an input value. It is a return value from some `stdio` functions, such as, err, `scanf()`. You're looking for it in the wrong place.

Comment: @user207421 I also tried while(!EOF) can you please elaborate how to do this since that didn't work either.

Comment: That makes even less sense, and it certainly has nothing to do with what I said above. Think about it. Where are you storing the value returned by `scanf()`? and, therefore, which variable should you be testing for equality with EOF?

Comment: Ahh got it, sorry I figured it out thanks! I should be doing if (s==EOF).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compare the result returned by `scanf` to EOF, not the out parameter that receives the typed input value.

That is, replace this:

```
    int s = scanf("%d", &x);
    if (x == EOF) {
        break;
    }
```

With this:

```
    int s = scanf("%d", &x);
    if (s == EOF) { 
        break;
    }
```